# React Image not extending the height

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have images that are showing up like this:

[image: 1]

The idea is that the images should extend to the bottom of the page. I have placeholder images as I'm trying to learn. Any idea why it might not be working? I'm really just trying to do this so I understand the underlying concept of designing a page. Thanks for your all your help!

Here's the code:

```
{<div className="directory">

  <div
    className="item"
    style={{
      backgroundImage: `url(${Stock1})`
    }}
  >

      <a>
      Stock 1
      </a>
  </div>
  <div
      className="item"
      style={{
        backgroundImage: `url(${Stock2})`
    }}
  >
      <a>
      Stock 2
      </a>

  </div>
</div>}
```

items =

```
    {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
  }
```

For the container, which sits on default.scss:

```
    {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 6.5rem);
  max-width: 1450px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

6.5rem being the height of the header.

Answer (score 0):

The 100% is only in relation to its container. If I'm understanding you correctly, you want the background image to fill the entire screen's height which you could use: 100vh which is the total height of the user's screen

Comment: The last piece of code I have is the container which sits on the default.scss. Is that tthe height you are referring to?

Comment: You would need to put the height rule on each item. So:
    height: 100vh;

Answer (score 0):

It's the style of item. try change height